# How to buy tickets for Canadian NHL games?

Tags: canada, sports-events

My question is very simple. I will do my vacation in Canada this year. What is the best possibility to buy ticket for NHL game? Official site NHL.com doesn't sell tickets for all games.
I have found several possibilities on the internet, probably somebody can recommend me most sure site, where I can pay without being overcharged.

Comment: Make sure you go in season then. Check ticketmaster.com - they sell tickets to the games.  Just checked, there are some available at the moment.

Comment: @Aleks G thank you, I know this site. I want some tickets for November, they are not avalaible currently

Comment: Stubhub seems to be reliable, in my experience. If you fail to get something you can always try showing up at the venue at game time and negotiate with the ubiquitous scalpers. Depending on the degree of suckage (Leafs?) the tickets may even be under face value.

Comment: @Spehro Pefhany, yes - Leafs, first game Toronto vs Vancouver at 14 November and second game Ottawa vs Philadelphia at 21 November (be 7 days in Toronto and 5 days in Ottawa). Thank you for your recommendation

Comment: Do you know which team/city you will be looking for, or is your plan to choose your travel destination based on where NHL tickets are cheapest?

Comment: I know already my destination, I will visit Ontario, namely Toronto for 7 days (between 12 and 19 November) and Ottawa for 5 days (between 19 and 24 November).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about sporting events, not travel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The official seller of NHL tickets is [Ticketmaster](http://www.ticketmaster.ca/browse/hockey-catid-9/sports-rid-10004/toronto-hamilton-and-area-dma-509). Following the usual links will get you to their hockey section. As you say, tickets for November are not yet on sale. Be aware that Maple Leafs tickets sell out pretty quickly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Can you please tell me, when is a start for a tickets selling for november on this site (approximately)?

Comment: Generally, single game tickets go on sale in mid-september. Keep an eye also on sites like http://www.stubhub.com, which is (officially sanctioned, and) used by many season ticket holders to offload tickets to games that they can't attend - sometimes at a steep discount!

Comment: Thank you very much to all people, which help me with a ticket. I have bought the ticket for Toronto vs Vancouver game at November 14! Thank you very much!